# Loop through JSON multidimentional array using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I've been trying to understand some of the documentation available regarding multidimensional arrays and JSON parsing, but I am just not grasping the concept.  I was hoping someone could help me understand a bit more.

I have the following JSON:

```
var obj1 = {

"couples": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "state": ME",
        "attributes": [
            {
                "NAME": "John & Jane",
                "BABY": "Kristen"
            }
```

I am trying to output the states of each couple in a table row (there are multiple, I just cut the JSON short for the sake of example.

Here's my code, what am I doing wrong?

```
document.write('<table><tr>');
var i;
for (i = 0; i < obj1.couples.length; i++) {
document.write('<td>' + couples[i].state);
}
```

Also, how might i get the name of the couple?

Comment: Avoid using `document.write`

Comment: It's not well-formed JSON. Use jsonlint.com for check your json formatting

Comment: Your missing the `obj1.` in your `write` statement. `document.write('<td>' + obj1.couples[i].state);`

Comment: Also, missing a quote on the actual state in the example.

Comment: That isn't JSON, it's JavaScript.

Comment: Quentin I put it into an object so I can have easier access.  Any other thoughts?